# How to count function calls for tree traversal

Tags: c, tree

I have written tree code. And I want to call it by any order in any function by any function call. i.e if I have

```
void inorder() {
    inorder();
    display();
    preorder();
}

void preorder() {
    inorder();
    display() ;
    postorder();
}

void postorder() {
    postorder();
    display();
    postorder();
}
```

In this I have called first `inorder` then again `inorder` then `preorder` likewise how can I display function what I have called by sequence?

Comment: This question is unreadable and impossible to understand at the current form. Please, think how can you reword it.

Answer (score 0):

I try my best understanding. Excuse me if I misunderstood.

You mean you want to see how the functions are called in a tree tructure.
Then you can define a tree strucutre to store the function name. Make the construct globally accessible or pass as the parameter in each function. Everytime, you call a function, you create a tree node and put its children (here the internal called fucntions) in it by using linked list.
The process is gonna be like a DFS, only thing you need is a well-defined construct.